# Adding widgets to QGridLayout at same position in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt

I have tested adding widgets(`QFrame`) to a `QGridLayout` at the `same position` & it is working fine. Due to the rigidity of code I cannot add a `Stacked Widget`. So I am adding the `Widgets` in the same position & making all (except the one I want to display) `hide` by `setVisible(false);`
Is this method fine or is my code running by chance & might crash some day?
Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

Qt's help does not forbid you to do this, though this code is strange. I would definitely recomend you to use `QStackedLayout`, or, at least, `QHBoxLayout`.